# Appropriate Slicing a DataFrame with datetime indices within a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, mypy

This more of a object type related question, but I'm also getting a `mypy` error as well. So there must be a better way to do it.

To the point:

I'm loading timeseries with my following function:

```
def load_something_between_two_days(
    "some_path",
    start: Optional[str] = None,
    end: Optional[str] = None,
):
    df = pd.read_parquet(some_path) # index is assumed to be datetime, no shitty format
    if start is not None:
        df.index = df[start:]
    if end is not None:
        df.index = df[:end]
return df
```

mypy error:
`error: Slice index must be an integer or None`

My first assumption would be to rather use `.loc`. But the `Optional` tag is still in my definition. And probably `mypy´ is not happy about the weird` DataFrame` slicing. So what's the best way to deal with this? I'm also not sure if I'm not tackling any fundemental coding principles.

Is StackOverflow even the right place to ask this type of question? :D

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) :

```
def load_something_between_two_days(
    some_path: str,
    start: Optional[str] = None,
    end: Optional[str] = None,
):
    df = pd.read_parquet(some_path).loc[start:end]

    return df
```

Or, if you have a named index, you can avoid loading the whole [parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#parquet) by using `filters` :

```
def load_something_between_two_days(
    some_path: str,
    start: Optional[str] = None,
    end: Optional[str] = None,
):
    filters = []

    if start is not None:
        filters.append(("index", ">=", pd.Timestamp(start)))

    if end is not None:
        filters.append(("index", "<=", pd.Timestamp(end)))
        
    df = pd.read_parquet(some_path, filters=filters or None)
    
    return df
```

*NB : Index level names, if specified, must be strings (here, `"index"`).*